# Why doesn’t my Swift array extension work?

Tags: swift

I am trying to run this code, and this error is being triggered

`Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'`

What am I doing wrong?

```
extension Array {        
    mutating func random100() {
        for _ in 0 ... 99 {
            self.append(Int(arc4random() % 10)) // Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Int)'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: extension Array where Element: Int { ... } 
like this? I tried but another error "Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Int'", and it's a compiler error.

Comment: You cannot contraint `Array` directly on its type. You must pass by protocols, look at my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I benefited a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must constraint your extension to `Int` types :

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Iterator.Element == Int {
    mutating func random100() {
        for _ in 1...100 {
            append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
        }
    }
}
```

And as you cannot directly constraint `Array`, you must constraint the protocol where the `append` method is defined.

Then you can use it on any array of `Int`:

```
var myArray = [3,5,6]
myArray.random100()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you really want? If you want a method that gives you a hundred random Ints, you’d better create a static method on Array. Mutating any array in general does not make sense – what if it’s a list of strings?
2. Take a look at `arc4random_uniform` to avoid modulo bias. I don’t know if the bias would be apparent in this case, but it’s a good practice to use `arc4random_uniform` anyway.